# Como separar uma String de acordo com um separador em C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho uma string nesse formato:

```
string valores = "Numero1#Numero2#Numero3#Numero4#";
```

Como faço para dívidi-la em um array de inteiros para obter isso:

```
int Numero[1] = Numero1;
int Numero[2] = Numero2;
int Numero[3] = Numero3;
int Numero[4] = Numero4;
```

Tentei algo assim mas não rolou:

```
cod_cg_meta_periodo.Split("#",System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Como não rolou? Deu erro? Deu um resultado inesperado?

Comment: Apareceu esse erro Error 64 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Sua chamada não funciona pois o primeiro parâmetro deve ser um array de chars, e não um único char.

Comment: Editei a minha resposta para exemplificar o uso correto.

Comment: Só uma dúvida @JoaoPaulo é um array de string então ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `string.Split`:

```
var array = valores.Split('#');
```

Se quiser passar opções, terá de fazer assim:

```
var array = valores.Split(new char[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Ou então quando o separador for uma string mais complexa:

```
var array = valores.Split(new string[] { "#" }, // lista de separadores complexos
                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Esse do meio funcionou legal. Achei que podia usar apenas um caractere string para fazer a divisão, mas ele pede array de char mesmo. Quando permitir marco como resolvido. Obrigado!

Comment: Só mais uma coisa. Para eu usar os valores, como faço? A primeira string sera array[0] ?

Comment: Na string que usou na questão, usando a opção `RemoveEmptyEntries`, fica assim o array: `[0] => "Numero1"`; `[1] => "Numero2"`; `[2] => "Numero3"` e `[3] => "Numero4"`.

Answer (score 4):

*Array de String*

```
string valores = "numero1#numero2#numero3#numero4#";
string[] itemValores = valores.Split('#');
```

*Para ler suas posições*

```
foreach (var item in itemValores)
{
    //item tem o valor de cada item da lista itemValores            
}

if (itemValores.Count() > 0)
{
   var str = itemValores[0];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Se o objetivo for interpretar os números na string como inteiros, você pode fazer o seguinte:
Para:

```
string valores = "1#2#3#4#";
int[] numeros;
```

Separa a string e cria um array para armazenar os números.

```
string[] numeros_str = valores.Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
numeros = new int[numeros_str.Length];
```

Interpreta as strings que contém os números.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
{
    numeros[i] = Int32.Parse(numeros_str[i]);
}
```

---

Outra opção, acredito que seja melhor, é, utilizando LINQ:

```
string valores = "1#2#3#4#";
int[] numeros = valores.Split(new string[] {"#"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: Com LINQ também fica bacana assim: `valores.Split('#').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray()`

Comment: Realmente, fica melhor. Vou editar. Obrigado.