# Verificar string Regex C#

Tags: c#, string, regex

Tenho uma string que somente pode ser composta por `X` maiúsculo e por `-`. 
Exemplo : `X-XX-XX` ou então `X-X-X-XX-XXX`. Onde a cada `-` seria contado um grupo e cada `X` um dígito.

Exemplo 1: a string  `X-XX-XX` possui 3 grupos, o primeiro grupo contém 1 digito, o segundo contém 2 dígitos e terceiro também contém 2 dígitos.

Exemplo 2: a string  `X-X-X-XX-XXX` possui 5 grupos, o primeiro grupo contém 1 digito, o segundo contém 1 dígitos e terceiro também contém 1 dígitos o quarto contém 2 dígitos e o quinto contém 3 dígitos.

Como faço para obter as informações conforme descrito no exemplo 1 e 2.

Já tentei assim, para contar a quantidade de grupos:

```
    public static int ValidaMascaraPlanoDeContas(string Mascara)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"([X])\w+/g");
        var match = regex.Match(Mascara);

        return match.Groups.Count;

    }
```

Já tentei vários string patterns e nada, como estou travado no grupo não sei qual o procedimento para contar os dígitos de cada grupo.

Comment: os dados são sempre X ou dígitos ?

Comment: O usuário poderá digitar qualquer sequencia de `X`?

Comment: Os 'X' são a mascara que o individuo ira utilizar posteriormente. Exemplo o 'X-XX-XX' vai se tornal '1-01-01', '1-01-02'. Mas no momento quero contar a quantidade de 'X' que foi adicionado na mascara.

Comment: Sim, pode digital qualquer sequencia, 'XXXX-X' ou 'XX-XXXX-X' o usuário que escolhe.

Comment: isso poderia te ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14619/como-separar-uma-string-de-acordo-com-um-separador-em-c

Comment: Pode sim, apos fazer o split eu podeira contar a quantidade de caracteres. Não havia pensado no split. Qual seria o "correto", usar o split, regex? Dá para fazer com linq também ?

Comment: Eu acredito que como você quer contar a quantidade de caracteres em cada grupo entre `-` basta usar o split, e realizar um loop para contar quantos caracteres tem cada grupo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50407/discussion-between-r-santos-and-robss70).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu usaria o próprio C# para fazer isso com o método Split;

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string teste = "X-X-X-XX-XXX";

        string[] grupos = teste.Split('-');

        Console.WriteLine(grupos.Length);

        foreach(var grupo in grupos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(grupo.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cAVDsA)